# What is the relation between the "Jacobins" and the "Montagnards" (French Revolution)?

Tags: french-revolution

What is the relation between the "[Jacobins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobins)" and the "[Montagnards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mountain)" (French Revolution)?

Seems the Montagnards were members of the Jacobins club.

Do they have the same ideas?

I did check the Wikipedia pages, and other encyclopedia resources, as well as some other multimedia presentations

Comment: What research have you done already? Have you checked the corresponding Wikipedia pages for each faction?

Comment: @SteveBird I did check the Wikipedia pages, and other encyclopedia resources, as well as some other multimedia presentations

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobins#Polarization_between_Robespierrists_and_Girondins) doesn't answer the question,

> ". . .  a polarization process started among the members of the Jacobin Club, between a group around Robespierre – after September 1792 called 'Montagnards' or 'Montagne', in English 'the Mountain' – and the Girondins. These groups never had any official status, nor official memberships. The Mountain was not even very homogenous in their political views: what united them was their aversion to the Girondins." *[Wikipedia:Jacobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobins#Polarization_between_Robespierrists_and_Girondins)*

The Montagnards were united in their opposition to the [Girondin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girondins) who

> . . . campaigned for the end of the monarchy, but then resisted the spiraling momentum of the Revolution, which caused a conflict with the more radical Montagnards. *[Wikipedia:Girondin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girondins)*

And for war

> Maximilien Robespierre, also a Jacobin, strongly pleaded against war with Prussia and Austria – but in the Jacobin Club, not in the Assembly where he was not seated. **Disdainfully, Robespierre addressed those Jacobin war promoters as 'the faction from the Gironde'; some, not all of them, were indeed from department Gironde. The Assembly in April 1792 finally decided for war, thus following the 'Girondin' line on it,** but Robespierre's place among the Jacobins had now become much more prominent *[Wikipedia:Jacobins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobins#Polarization_between_Robespierrists_and_Girondins)*

Comment: Why are we answering (obvious) High School essay questions?